# Ayuda con Middleware Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

tengo dos tipos de usuarios Administrador y Vendedor, el Administrador tiene acceso a todo, pero el vendedor a ciertos modulos, pero cuando escribo en la url del usuario vendedor accede a todos los modulos ayuda por favor

mi route web.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['guest']], function () {

Route::get('/','Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm');
Route::post('/', 'Auth\LoginController@login')->name('login');


});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {

Route::post('/logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');


Route::group(['middleware' => ['Vendedor']], function () {

     Route::resource('producto', 'ProductoController');
     Route::resource('cliente', 'ClienteController');
     Route::resource('venta', 'VentaController');


});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['Administrador']], function () {

    Route::resource('producto','ProductoController');
    Route::resource('cliente','ClienteController');
    Route::resource('proveedor','ProveedorController');
    Route::resource('rol','RolController');
    Route::resource('user','UserController');

});
});
```

como pueden ver tienen routes en comun, como se podria hacer para que el usuario vendedor no pueda acceder mediante url a las vistas que no tiene acceso, ya aprobe añadiendo el constructor en los controladores

mi clase usuario

```
use Notifiable;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'id','nombre','tipo_documento','num_documento','direccion','telefono','email', 'usuario', 'password','condicion','idrol','imagen'
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];

public function roles(){
    return $this->belongsTo('\App\Rol','idrol');
}

/**
 * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $casts = [
    'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
];
//Debe existir el rol
//lista de roles autorizados
public function authorizeRoles($roles)
{
    abort_unless($this->hasAnyRole($roles), 401);
    return true;
}
public function hasAnyRole($roles)
{
    if (is_array($roles)) {
        foreach ($roles as $role) {
            if ($this->hasRole($role)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    } else {
        if ($this->hasRole($roles)) {
             return true; 
        }   
    }
    return false;
}
public function hasRole($role)
{
    if ($this->roles()->where('nombre', $role)->first()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
```

gracias de antemano

Comment: Estad diciendo que Vendedor puede entrar a Proveedor, Rol y User?

Comment: exacto puede acceder mediante url